# how to use rowIterator startign from Different Row num than zero

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
    {
        FileInputStream F = new FileInputStream("C://test.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(F);
        HSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = s.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
}
```

anybody can help me with it ?
anybody can help me with it. ?

Answer (score 1):

The Sheet has a `getRow` method which take the row index as integer, you may use that one to loop on the rows from the row you want.